# PHP7 : install ext-dom issue

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.4, php-7

I'm running laravel 5.4 on Ubuntu 16.04 server with PHP7. trying to install `cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable` package throw some error:

```
pish@let:/home/sherk/ftp/www$ sudo composer require cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Using version ^4.2 for cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - phpunit/php-code-coverage 4.0.7 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/php-code-coverage 4.0.7 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for phpunit/php-code-coverage (installed at 4.0.7) -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[4.0.7].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I have no problem installing this package on local version of the app .

Comment: best way is  " sudo apt-get install php7.4-mysql php7.4-mbstring php7.4-xml "

Answer (score 712, accepted):

First of all, read the warning! It says do **not** run composer as **root**! 
Secondly, you're probably using Xammp on your local which has the required php libraries as default.

But in your server you're missing `ext-dom`. `php-xml` has all the related packages you need. So, you can simply install it by running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install php-xml
```

Most likely you are missing `mbstring` too. If you get the error, install this package as well with:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
```

Then run:

```
composer update
composer require cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable
```

Comment: thanks . if i dont use `sudo` for running composer, get this error :`Could not read /home/pish/.composer/auth.json                                                
  file_get_contents(/home/pish/.composer/auth.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied `

Comment: its a permission issue  search for chmod and chown commands. Change permission and owner of this folder you will be fine.

Comment: @rodrane there's a typo in your code for installing the `php-mbstring` package, it should be `sudo apt-get`. Other than that; it works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: I installed php7.0-xml on my machine but composer still throw me this error when I do a `composer install`

Comment: @SalustianoMuniz You might have to enable the modules in PHP. For example, use `sudo phpenmod xml` and do the same for `xmlreader` & `xmlwriter`. Then restart your server (if apache: `sudo service apache2 restart`) and try to install again.

Comment: Or sudo apt-get install php7.2-xml if you are into 7.2.x

Comment: : Unable to locate package php7.1-xml
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.1-xml'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1-xml'

Comment: Thanks fix my problem.For php 7.2 use this

      sudo apt-get install php7.2-xml

Comment: Is there somewhere we can match missing extensions to actual packages? Only after trying (and failing) to install php7.3-dom, php7.3-extdom, php7.3-ext-dom did I finally google to find the right package php7.3-xml here.

Comment: php-zip package is also needed.

Comment: sudo apt install php-xml is the key

Comment: You need to install php-xml based on your PHP version.
eg: if your PHP version is 7.4 => sudo apt-get install php7.4-xml

Answer (score 112):

`sudo apt install php-xml` will work but the thing is it will download the plugin for the latest PHP version.

If your PHP version is not the latest, then you can add version in it:

```
# PHP 7.2:
sudo apt install php7.2-xml

# PHP 7.3
sudo apt install php7.3-xml


# PHP 7.4
sudo apt install php7.4-xml

# PHP 8
sudo apt install php8.0-xml

# PHP 8.2 (latest)
sudo apt install php-xml
```

Comment: I'm running 7.3 and someone else was saying to install "php-xml", so I did, but I still had the exact same problem. Once you see how simple it is it's easy to understand, but I completely missed it until seeing this answer. Installing php7.3-xml solved my problem.

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution. By mistake the php 8 extension was installed. How do I remove it?

Comment: You may try `sudo apt-get remove php-xml` @MrEduar

Answer (score 10):

For CentOS, RHEL, Fedora:

```
$ yum search php-xml
============================================================================================================ N/S matched: php-xml ============================================================================================================
php-xml.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which use XML
php-xmlrpc.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which use the XML-RPC protocol
php-xmlseclibs.noarch : PHP library for XML Security
php54-php-xml.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which use XML
php54-php-xmlrpc.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which use the XML-RPC protocol
php55-php-xml.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which use XML
php55-php-xmlrpc.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which use the XML-RPC protocol
php56-php-xml.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which use XML
php56-php-xmlrpc.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which use the XML-RPC protocol
php70-php-xml.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which use XML
php70-php-xmlrpc.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which use the XML-RPC protocol
php71-php-xml.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which use XML
php71-php-xmlrpc.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which use the XML-RPC protocol
php72-php-xml.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which use XML
php72-php-xmlrpc.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which use the XML-RPC protocol
php73-php-xml.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which use XML
php73-php-xmlrpc.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which use the XML-RPC protocol
```

Then select the **php-xml** version matching your php version:

```
# php -v
PHP 7.2.11 (cli) (built: Oct 10 2018 10:00:29) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

# sudo yum install -y php72-php-xml.x86_64
```

Answer (score -1):

you need just update your local composer file:

- first you need remove "composer.lock" file from you app
- then, exec in your bash:

```bash
composer update --ignore-platform-req=ext-curl
```

- so try again

```bash
composer require cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable
```