# Yii2 error - Class 'yii\mongodb\ActiveRecord' not found

Tags: php, mongodb, activerecord, yii, yii2

I have done setup for mongodb on my system with Yii2 basic.

I have also installed the extension for mongodb (yii2-mongodb) inside a directory /vendor/yiisoft and checked for the permissions.

Now I am testing the connection with a controller and model but I am getting the following error.

> PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException Class
>
> 'yii\mongodb\ActiveRecord' not found

Is there anything that needs to be installed?

Comment: Did you install yii2-mongodb using composer?

Comment: Yes I installed it using composer and on updating composer I am getting error i.e your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Comment: So it looks like you have not installed it. Probably you are missing MongoDB PHP extension.

Comment: I am using PHP Version 7 and MongoDB extension version :1.2.8 is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Have you install yii2/mongodb by composer ^^?

```
composer require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-mongodb
```

Or your try follow this [official Yii2 document](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-mongodb-index.html) step by step maybe can help you up :)!

Comment: You cannot directly copy the library file to the vendor directory, the composer autoloader can't detect the library. Erm i saw you say that you using composer and on updating composer getting error right? Can you paste the error here let us see maybe can help you up

Comment: Here is the error : Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Comment: @user2531706 sorry for late reply, I face this 'minimum-stability' problem before, on that time I have do many research. You can backup your whole project then delete the 'vendor' folder then run `composer update` to reinstall all package again. This how before I solve my problem.

Comment: This works for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408604/php7-install-ext-dom-issue

Answer (score 1):

In this case I tried following command before updating composer to fulfill the packages that need to update the composer

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml
```

most likely you are missing mbstring too . If you get the error install this package as well.

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
```

then run

```
composer require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-mongodb
composer update
```

Will work!!!