# php dependency/package manager Composer will not install packages

Tags: php, nginx, composer-php, slim

I'm building a website with PHP framework ["Slim"](https://www.slimframework.com/) as my templating framework, and it recommends using composer as the package manager. SO... I'm now using composer for the first time, developing locally on 64 bit Ubuntu 16.04 and composer *is not installing anything into my project*.

I've followed the installation instructions on the Slim Framework & Composer websites to a tee.

Basically this is the order of what I've done:

1. Installed composer into `/var/www/html` directory **[1.]**
2. Created Slim project using Slim-Skeleton as a base

   > > php composer.phar create-project slim/slim-skeleton slimLittleTest

Note: the `php composer.phar create-project slim/slim-skeleton` command automatically creates a `composer.json` file, I will put the contents of that file down farther in my question.

3. Change into that directory and run `php composer.phar install`
4. Nothing is installed!

If I try to run `php -S localhost:8080 -t public public/index.php` as you're now supposed to able to (from the Slim framework website homepage tutorial) I get the following error:

```
[Tue Sep  5 18:55:04 2017] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/slimLittleTest/public/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/slimLittleTest/public/index.php on line 12
[Tue Sep  5 18:55:05 2017] PHP Warning:  
require(/var/www/html/slimLittleTest/public/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/slimLittleTest/public/index.php on line 12
```

This error of course makes sense because nothing got installed! There is no `vendor/autoload.php` because Composer hasn't installed anything. (By default Composer installs dependencies into the `vendor` folder in the root of your project)

**SEPTEMBER 7th QUESTION UPDATE**

From some comments down below, I've been alerted to the fact that something must have gone wrong on the command `composer create-project`, that my solution of just re-requiring all packages shouldn't be necessary. Upon further inspection, I did get some errors upon running command `php composer.phar create-project slim/slim-skeleton projectName`. Below is exactly what got output from the console after running that command:

```
php composer.phar create-project slim/slim-skeleton tester
Installing slim/slim-skeleton (3.1.2)
  - Installing slim/slim-skeleton (3.1.2): Loading from cache
 Created project in tester
 Loading composer repositories with package information
 Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
 Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.9 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.8 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.7 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
   [.......]

 To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-imagick.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Would either that `.ini extensions` issue or `Problem 1 php unit requires ext-dom` issue be the main source of my problem?

Comment: have you created a `composer.json` file to declare your project's dependencies ?

Comment: yep. there is one created automatically by the `create-project slim/slim-skeleton [project_name]` command. I will edit the question to make that clearer!

Comment: when installing , try `composer -vvv install` to get (highly verbose) status.  Also run `composer info` in your directory , see what gives, and when in doubt, there is also the highly useful `composer -help`

Comment: hey thanks mate, just found a solution moments ago though. @YvesLeBorg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got lucky and stumbled upon an answer that worked in my situation.

I just had to run `php composer.phar require [package_name]`, for each package name, and if it wasn't in composer.json yet that dependency would get installed. So what I needed to do was delete the composer.json file, then go back and require each package from it. Nothing else worked, such as `php composer.phar update`, or `php composer.phar install`.

So I ran `php composer.phar  require slim/php`, `php composer.phar require php`, etc. from the command line and everything installed correctly.

This is potentially a failure of the getting started documentation from [SlimFramework.com](https://www.slimframework.com/), It's not necessarily "wrong" because maybe it works in some/most situations, but they should at least address the potential for the problem I ran into, and a solution or way to avoid it.

**EVEN BETTER SOLUTION**

Turns out that the main error I was getting here is that I was **missing ext-dom**. Thank you to this badass [@Anar Bayramov's answer on another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408604/php7-install-ext-dom-issue) I know that I can get the missing **ext-dom** by simply downloading **php7.0-xml**.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml
```

And BOOM! Now when I run `php composer.phar create-project slim/slim-skeleton projectName` all vendor packages are installed successfully and it works like a charm. Problem solved.

Comment: If that's necessary, something must have gone wrong before as `composer create-project` will automatically install all dependencies required by the application you are setting up. Are you sure that the `create-project` command did not run into any errors?

Comment: You do not need to do this. Something else went wrong n the beginning.

Comment: Ok this I'll put what the console output in the question then