# Laravel Project is not working Lampp & Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have install a laravel in a htdocs folder using following command. When I have start a project using artisan it not start.please review a things.

```
​sevenbits11@SBT-PC-11:/opt/lampp/htdocs$ sudo composer create-project laravel/laravel first-project --prefer-dist
sevenbits11@SBT-PC-11:/opt/lampp/htdocs/first-project$ php artisan serve
PHP Warning:  require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/first-project/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/first-project/artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/first-project/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/first-project/artisan on line 18
```

**Updated After Applied solution**

```
sudo php artisan serve
PHP Warning:  require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/first-project/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/first-project/artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/first-project/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/first-project/artisan on line 18
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the following dependency:

`sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml`

You can try refer the issues here: 
[PHP7 : install ext-dom issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408604/php7-install-ext-dom-issue)

Comment: sudo php artisan serve
PHP Warning:  require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/first-project/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/first-project/artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/first-project/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/first-project/artisan on line 18

Comment: Can you try running `composer update --no-scripts` and see the result if it is fixed?

Comment: should I install composer and both in same directory. do you have any referance?

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu 16.04, you can try check out this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-composer-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot says: "phpunit required ext-dom" ..

That means, you have to install PHP-XML extension in order to get phpunit and Laravel properly installed.

Comment: sudo php artisan serve
PHP Warning:  require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/first-project/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/first-project/artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/first-project/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/first-project/artisan on line 18

Comment: @VasimVanzara you need to read the error messages. "NO SUCH FILE OR DIRECTORY" means that there's no file called "`artisan`" inside your `/opt/lampp/htdocs/first-project/` directory. You need to install the PHP extension `php-xml` in order to properly install Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the correct extension for PHP try installing

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-dom
```

You may also need to install other packages to get everything to update.

Take a look at this link may help you https://askubuntu.com/questions/795629/install-php-extensions-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: sudo php artisan serve
PHP Warning:  require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/first-project/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/first-project/artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/first-project/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/first-project/artisan on line 18

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `ext-dom`, `php7.1-xml` has the packages you need, try installing it by running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml
```

Then run this command:

```
composer install
```

If you don't have a composer you can follow this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-composer-on-ubuntu-16-04) from Digital Ocean which is very clear.

You can also refer their tutorial which is [How To Deploy a Laravel Application with Nginx on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-laravel-application-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04).