# Laravel Composer install failed with error in ubuntu

Tags: laravel, composer-php, php-7.2

Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - Installation request for aws/aws-sdk-php 3.75.0 -> satisfiable by aws/aws-sdk-php[3.75.0].

```
- aws/aws-sdk-php 3.75.0 requires ext-simplexml * -> the requested PHP extension simplexml is missing from your system.
```

Problem 2
    - Installation request for erusev/parsedown 1.7.1 -> satisfiable by erusev/parsedown[1.7.1].

```
- erusev/parsedown 1.7.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
```

Problem 3
    - Installation request for laravel/framework v5.5.43 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.43].

```
- laravel/framework v5.5.43 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
```

Problem 4
    - Installation request for league/csv 9.1.4 -> satisfiable by league/csv[9.1.4].

```
- league/csv 9.1.4 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
```

Problem 5
    - Installation request for nicolaslopezj/searchable 1.10.3 -> satisfiable by nicolaslopezj/searchable[1.10.3].

```
- nicolaslopezj/searchable 1.10.3 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
```

Problem 6
    - Installation request for phpoffice/phpexcel 1.8.1 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpexcel[1.8.1].

```
- phpoffice/phpexcel 1.8.1 requires ext-xml * -> the requested PHP extension xml is missing from your system.
```

Problem 7
    - Installation request for phar-io/manifest 1.0.1 -> satisfiable by phar-io/manifest[1.0.1].

```
- phar-io/manifest 1.0.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
```

Problem 8
    - Installation request for phpunit/php-code-coverage 5.3.2 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[5.3.2].
    - phpunit/php-code-coverage 5.3.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.

Problem 9
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 6.5.13 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[6.5.13].

```
- phpunit/phpunit 6.5.13 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
```

Problem 10
    - Installation request for theseer/tokenizer 1.1.0 -> satisfiable by theseer/tokenizer[1.1.0].

```
- theseer/tokenizer 1.1.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
```

Problem 11
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 3.75.0 requires ext-simplexml * -> the requested PHP extension simplexml is missing from your system.

```
- league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 1.0.21 requires aws/aws-sdk-php ^3.0.0 -> satisfiable by aws/aws-sdk-php[3.75.0].

- Installation request for league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 1.0.21 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3[1.0.21].
```

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini

```
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini

- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini

- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini

- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini

- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini

- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini

- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini

- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini

- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini

- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini

- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini

- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini

- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini

- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini

- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini

- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini

- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini

- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini

- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
```

You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

---

What is that error means? I have all extensions mentioned above are available and enabled in my php.ini.

Comment: your php modules aren't enabled or installed, create a phpinfo file and check if everything required by laravel is enabled and installed.

Comment: apache restart is required

Comment: Have you enabled them in the correct php.ini? The error is suggesting that it is using the multiple ini files in the conf.d folder. You may want to check the extensions are enabled in those. Running php --ini will show you the order of php ini files.

Comment: They are enabled in the correct php.ini @Petay87

Comment: you can use this page content [PHP7 : install ext-dom issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408604/php7-install-ext-dom-issue)

Comment: In which file did you enable them?

Comment: They are enabled on default in php.ini @xabbuh

Comment: Can you please give the full path to the file that you modified?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP7 : install ext-dom issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408604/php7-install-ext-dom-issue)

Answer (score 18):

Try running:

```
sudo apt install php7.2-mbstring php7.2-xml
```

You are missing these extensions from your system and/or they are not configured to be enabled with php. This will install and enable them in your `php.ini` file.

Comment: Just the obvious hint, that if you have a different php version installed, you also need to adapt the install command, e.g. sudo apt install php8.2-mbstring php8.2-xml.