# Composer install, ext-dom missing - LEMP Centos 7

Tags: php, composer-php, centos7

When I run `composer install` I get the following error
`theseer/tokenizer 1.1.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system`

LEMP stack on Centos 7
7.3

I found elsewhere that I needed to install php-xml, which I did (from the remi repo)

How do I get past this error?

Comment: may be this can be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408604/php7-install-ext-dom-issue - there is second unswer for Centos

Comment: @myxaxa Thanks...saw that question and answer. I followed it to install php-xml

Answer (score 6):

Here is what I finally found and did:

I must have had the incorrect remi repo.
`sudo yum-config-manager --enable remi-php73` 
Then I reinstalled php-xml `sudo yum install php-xml`,br.

`composer install` then ran without error