# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

- phpunit/phpunit[dev-master, 9.3.3, ..., 9.4.x-dev] require ext-dom * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's dom extension.
- phpunit/phpunit 9.5.x-dev is an alias of phpunit/phpunit dev-master and thus requires it to be installed too.
- Root composer.json requires phpunit/phpunit ^9.3.3 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[9.3.3, ..., 9.5.x-dev (alias of dev-master)].

Comment: `Install or enable PHP's dom extension`

Comment: This might help you with installing the extension https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408604/php7-install-ext-dom-issue

Comment: i also do this think but not working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you run on ubuntu or another debian based OS `sudo apt install phpunit` should install this extension.

For development you can use [Docker](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop), see more details on the [Laravel 8](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x#your-first-laravel-project) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

## October, 2023 on Alpine linux

> - phpunit/phpunit[9.5.0, ..., 9.5.28] require ext-xmlwriter * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's xmlwriter extension.
> - Root composer.json requires phpunit/phpunit ~9.5.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[9.5.0, ..., 9.5.28].

```bash
apk add phpunit
```