# I cannot run the command php artisan test

Tags: php, laravel, testing

when I run `php artisan test` I got this message
`PHPUnit requires the "dom" extension.`
I already run `composer install`

Comment: see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408604/php7-install-ext-dom-issue

Comment: I solved the problem now but I got another error : ` SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
` when I run the command

Comment: Make sure the database is up and running. Also make sure you're trying to connect to it using the correct hostname/ip and port.

Comment: I am using sqlite in memory to run laravel test

Answer (score -1):

It is not a laravel issue. it's a PHP issue. you are missing extensions named php-xml and php-mbstring. install both extensions, restart the server and then error will be gone!